# Call method when modal closes in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue app (and I'm relatively new to Vue), anyway I have a generic error modal which is displayed when any of my `axios` calls fail.

On the `modal`, I want to be able to retry the failed process when the 'Retry' `button` is clicked but I'm struggling a bit on how to achieve this. I don't think `props` will help me as the `modal` is triggered by

```
VueEvent.$emit('show-error-modal')
```

I have managed in my `catch` to pass the `function` which has failed by using

```
 VueEvent.$emit('show-error-modal', (this.test));
```

Then in my `modal`, I have access to it using

```
created() {
    VueEvent.$on('show-error-modal', (processFailed) => {
        console.log('processFailed', processFailed)
        this.processFailed = processFailed;
        $('#errorModal').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', this.focus);
    });
}
```

Using 'F12' it gives

> ```
> test: function test() {
>       var _this2 = this;
>
>       var page = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : null;
>       alert('boo');
>       this.loading = true;
>       var order_by = {
>         'ho_manufacturers.name': 4,
>         'services.servicename': 4
>       };
>
>       axios.post('/test/url', {
>         id: this.selectedManufacturers,
>         page: page,
>         order_by: order_by
>       }).then(function (response) {
>         var paginator = response.data.paginator;
>
>         _this2.$store.dispatch('paginateProducts', paginator);
>
>         _this2.$store.dispatch('setProductPaginator', paginator);
>
>         _this2.loading = false;
>       })["catch"](function (error) {
>         var processFailed = 'fetchProducts';
>         _this2.loading = false;
>         VueEvent.$emit('show-error-modal', _this2.test);
>         console.log(error);
>       });
>     },
> ```

I don't think this is the right way of doing it though as all `this.` are replaced with `_this2` as shown above. I need the `modal` to be generic so I can reuse it but I can't figure it out how to retry the process when clicking the button.

The `modals` are registered in my `app.vue` file as

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- Other code here -->
        <app-error-modal />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
   // Other code here
   import ErrorModal from './components/ErrorModal';

   export default {
      name: 'App',

      components: {
         // Other code here
        appErrorModal: ErrorModal
      }

     // Other code here
</script>
```

Modal button HTML

```
<button ref="retryButton" class="btn btn-success col-lg-2" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" @click="retryProcess">Retry</button>
```

Modal `script` code

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "ErrorModal",

    created() {
        VueEvent.$on('show-error-modal', (processFailed) => {
            console.log('processFailed', processFailed)
            this.processFailed = processFailed;
            $('#errorModal').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', this.focus);
        });
    },

    methods: {
        focus() {
            this.$refs.retryButton.focus();
        },

        retryProcess() {
            //this.$parent.test();   TRIED THIS BUT DIDN'T WORK
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I'd rather not have to the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom event on your component

```
<div id="app">
    <error-modal v-if="isError" v-on:retry-clicked="retry"></error-modal>
    <button @click="isError = true">Make Error</button>
</div>


const errorModal = {
    template : "<button @click=\"$emit('retry-clicked')\">Retry</button>"
}

new Vue({
    el : "#app",
    data : {
        isError : false
    },
    components : {
        errorModal
    },
    methods : {
        retry : function(){
            this.isError = false;
            console.log("child component has called parent when retry clicked")
        }
    }
})
```

[Custom event on component - VUEJS DOC](https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have there looks correct. You are passing the function to retry ("test") as "processFailed" - I would call that something different such as retryFn.

Then in your error modal component you just need:

```
<button @click="processFailed">Retry</button>
```

Don't worry about what the browser shows you in F12, that is the transpiled Javascript, it will work fine.